# Which of these is the fastest way to check the case of a character?

Tags: python

I am learning Python from scratch. For the same, I am using the book ['How To Think Like a Computer Scientist'](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/) . Section 7.12 of the same deals with character classification and it lists 3 different ways of determining whether a 
given character (ch) is lowercase, as follows:

1.

```
    def is_lower(ch):    
        return string.find(string.lowercase, ch) != -1
```

2.

```
     def is_lower(ch):
         return ch in string.lowercase
```

3.

```
     def is_lower(ch):
         return 'a' <= ch <= 'z'
```

I was thinking which of these would be the the fastest for processing. I am concerned with only the processing time, not the memory requirements. I am guessing it is the third one because in the first two cases, the entire string may need to be processed till the end to find out whether the character is present at all, whereas in the third case, just two comparisons are sufficient and the whole string doesn't need to be processed. So is my guess right?

Comment: Why don't you test them? Run each function 1,000,000 times and measure the elapsed time.

Comment: What don't you use the built-in `ch.islower()`? Not need to write your own.

Comment: @deepmax I haven't yet reached that level where I can accurately measure the time taken by a certain function to execute. Theoretically I can indeed run the different ways a large number of times and then measure the difference but in that case the processor too should be equally idle during all 3 test runs, and that is practically not possible in my case.

Comment: Or better yet, use the `timeit` module rather than writing your own timing code.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That was helpful. However, given the book that I mentioned which I am learning from, I was not introduced to it yet, hence didn't know about it so far. Here the intention was to figure out which of the underlying implementations would have been the fastest, just like how ch.islower() too would have some implementation in Python.

Comment: @Blckknght I am learning Python from scratch. I have not yet reached a level where I can measure the performance / execution time of a function call. However, that was helpful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my test code using `timeit`:

```
import string
import timeit
import random

def is_lower(ch):
    return string.find(string.lowercase, ch) != -1

def is_lower1(ch):
    return ch in string.lowercase

def is_lower2(ch):
    return 'a' <= ch <= 'z'

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

for i in range(100):
    lt = random.choice(string.letters)
    wrappered1 = wrapper(is_lower, lt)
    wrappered2 = wrapper(is_lower1, lt)
    wrappered3 = wrapper(is_lower2, lt)
    t1, t2, t3 = [], [], []
    t1 += timeit.repeat(wrappered1, repeat=3, number=100000)
    t2 += timeit.repeat(wrappered2, repeat=3, number=100000)
    t3 += timeit.repeat(wrappered3, repeat=3, number=100000)

print 't1: ', sum(t1)/len(t1)
print 't2: ', sum(t2)/len(t2)
print 't2: ', sum(t3)/len(t3)
```

Output:

```
Out[44]:
t1:  0.0781290027991
t2:  0.0348194339546
t2:  0.0307262024573
```

It can be seen clearly, the last method is the fastest, while the first is the slowest.